# Fill index common matrix fields [STRANGE BUGS]

Tags: c++

It's my first time posting here, but I always look for some ideas between your posts.

I'm trying to fill the upper half of an array accordingly to the other filled cells (all with 0s and 1s), something like this:

```
if (matrix[3,2] == 1) and (matrix[3,1] == 1){
   matrix[2,1] = 1;}
```

After much trying, I've made something that barely works with:

```
   matrix[a][b] = 1;

   for (unsigned int i = 0; i < max_index; i++){
        if (matrix[i][a] == 1){
            matrix[i][b] = 1;
        }
    }
```

But all I can do is wait for a matrix[corner_i.v1][corner_i.v2] that fills some gaps that shouldn't exists... like this [0, 2]:

```
01011
00111
00011
00001
00000
```

Can you guys give me some advices or show some way that I can make this happen? Thank you all.

[edit 2]:

I figured out this was left, but the code still not working at 100%:

```
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < max_index; i++){           

    if (matriz[i][a] == 1){
        matriz[i][b] = 1;
    }

    else if (matriz[b][i] == 1){
        matriz[a][i] = 1;
    }
}
```

[Output be like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c8jMK.png)

[EDIT 3]:
I've solved part of the problem in the function `void conectar_matriz()`, but some of the inputs seems to bug the program, specially matrices over 40x40.

https://pastebin.com/L3GsciK0

Comment: It's not clear to me what you are trying to do. Do you want the upper right half filled with ones and the rest with zeros?

Comment: Yes! But it's not a big problem if the left half ended being filled, It's not readed at all, same with the diagonal.

Comment: If it's not a problem how the rest of the matrix is filled then why not fill the whole matrix with ones? I'm afraid I don't really understand.

Comment: Can you provide us the example of what the input and what the output should be?

Comment: `for (std::size_t i = 0; i < max_index; i++) { for (std::size_t j = i + 1; j < max_index; j++) { matrix[i][j] = 1; } }`?

Comment: I'm sorry... I really didn't explained the problem. The main problem is because I'm trying to solve Kurskal in a different way. The matrix must be filled in order to show the relation between the vertexes and the already filled edges.